# Are interval, segment, fenwick trees the same?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, fenwick-tree

Today i listened a lecture about fenwick trees (binary indexed trees) and the teacher says than this tree is a generalization of interval and segment trees, but my implementations of this three data structures are different.
Is this afirmation true? and Why?

Comment: There is a difference between stating that "A is a generalization of B" and "A is the same as B."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have never heard [binary indexed trees](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees) called a generalization of anything. It's certainly not a generalization of [interval trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) and [segment trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree). I suggest you follow the links to convince yourself of this.

> than this tree is a generalization of interval and segment trees

If by "this tree" your teacher meant "the binary indexed tree", then he is wrong.

> but my implementations of this three data structures are different

Of course they are different, your teacher never said they shouldn't be. He just said one is a generalization of the other (which isn't true, but still). Either way, the implementations are supposed to be different.

What would have the same implementation is a binary indexed tree and a fenwick tree, because **those** are **the same thing**.

Comment: i saw the topcoder's article and many querys in BIT are similar of interval trees.

Comment: They may be similar, but that doesn't mean you can say that one data structure derives from another. A node in the interval tree holds one half of the interval its parent node holds, while a node in a BIT holds an interval given by the binary representation of a number.

Answer (score 13):

The following classification seems sensible although different people are bound to mix these terms up.

**Fenwick tree/Binary-indexed tree** [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree)

The one where you use a single array and operations on the binary representation to store prefix sums (also called cumulative sums). Elements can be members of a monoid.

**Range tree** [link](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor)

The family of trees where each node represents a subrange of a given range, say [0, N]. Used to compute associative operations on intervals.

**Interval tree** [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree)

Trees where you store actual intervals. Most commonly you take a midpoint, keep the intersecting intervals at the node and repeat the process for the intervals to the left and to the right of the point.

**Segment tree** [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree)

Similar to a range tree where leaves are elementary intervals in a possibly continuous space rather than discrete and higher nodes are unions of the elementary intervals. Used to check for point inclusion.