# Histogram approximation for streaming data

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, machine-learning, histogram

This question is a slight extension of the one [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385700/calculating-a-histogram-on-a-streaming-data-online-histogram-calculation). I am working on re-implementing a version of the histogram approximation found in Section 2.1 of [this paper](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume11/ben-haim10a/ben-haim10a.pdf), and I would like to get all my ducks in a row before beginning this process again. Last time, I used `boost::multi_index`, but performance wasn't the greatest, and I would like to avoid the logarithmic in number of buckets insert/find complexity of a `std::set`. Because of the number of histograms I'm using (one per feature per class per leaf node of a random tree in a random forest), the computational complexity must be as close to constant as possible.

A standard technique used to implement a histogram involves mapping the input real value to a bin number. To accomplish this, one method is to:

1. initialize a standard C array of size N, where N = number of bins; and
2. multiply the input value (real number) by some factor and floor the result to get its index in the C array.

This works well for histograms with uniform bin size, and is quite efficient. However, Section 2.1 of the above-linked paper provides a histogram algorithm without uniform bin sizes.

Another issue is that simply multiplying the input real value by a factor and using the resulting product as an index fails with negative numbers. To resolve this, I considered identifying a '0' bin somewhere in the array. This bin would be centered at 0.0; the bins above/below it could be calculated using the same multiply-and-floor method just explained, with the slight modification that the floored product be added to two or subtracted from two as necessary.

This then raises the question of merges: the algorithm in the paper merges the two closest bins, as measured from center to center. In practice, this creates a 'jagged' histogram approximation, because some bins would have extremely large counts and others would not. Of course, this is due to non-uniform-sized bins, and doesn't result in any loss of precision. A loss of precision does, however, occur if we try to normalize the non-uniform-sized bins to make the uniform. This is because of the assumption that m/2 samples fall to the left and right of the bin center, where m = bin count. We could model each bin as a gaussian, but this will still result in a loss of precision (albeit minimal)

So that's where I'm stuck right now, leading to this major question: **What's the best way to implement a histogram accepting streaming data and storing each sample in bins of uniform size?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep four variables.

```
int N;  // assume for simplicity that N is even
int count[N];
double lower_bound;
double bin_size;
```

When a new sample `x` arrives, compute `double i = floor(x - lower_bound) / bin_size`. If `i >= 0 && i < N`, then increment `count[i]`. If `i >= N`, then repeatedly double `bin_size` until `x - lower_bound < N * bin_size`. On every doubling, adjust the counts (optimize this by exploiting sparsity for multiple doublings).

```
for (int j = 0; j < N / 2; j++) count[j] = count[2 * j] + count[2 * j + 1];
for (int j = N / 2; j < N; j++) count[j] = 0;
```

The case `i < 0` is trickier, since we need to decrease `lower_bound` as well as increase `bin_size` (again, optimize for sparsity or adjust the counts in one step).

```
while (lower_bound > x) {
    lower_bound -= N * bin_size;
    bin_size += bin_size;
    for (int j = N - 1; j > N / 2 - 1; j--) count[j] = count[2 * j - N] + count[2 * j - N + 1];
    for (int j = 0; j < N / 2; j++) count[j] = 0;
}
```

The exceptional cases are expensive but happen only a logarithmic number of times in the range of your data over the initial bin size.

If you implement this in floating-point, be mindful that floating-point numbers are not real numbers and that statements like `lower_bound -= N * bin_size` may misbehave (in this case, if `N * bin_size` is much smaller than `lower_bound`). I recommend that `bin_size` be a power of the radix (usually two) at all times.